# Php, How do I choose the arrays with the weather exactly at today's date?

Tags: php, arrays

I get an array of this kind:

```
Array
      (
     [0] => Array
(
    [dt] => 1523728800
    [main] => Array
        (
            [temp] => 16.84
            [temp_min] => 15.73
            [temp_max] => 16.84
            [pressure] => 1001.67
            [sea_level] => 1036.08
            [grnd_level] => 1001.67
            [humidity] => 66
            [temp_kf] => 1.11
        )

    [weather] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 800
                    [main] => Clear
                    [description] => clear sky
                    [icon] => 01n
                )

        )


    [dt_txt] => 2018-04-14 18:00:00
)

[1] => Array
    (
        [dt] => 1523739600
        [main] => Array
            (
                [temp] => 12.97
                [temp_min] => 12.23
                [temp_max] => 12.97
                [pressure] => 1002.14
                [sea_level] => 1036.93
                [grnd_level] => 1002.14
                [humidity] => 67
                [temp_kf] => 0.74
            )

        [weather] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 800
                        [main] => Clear
                        [description] => clear sky
                        [icon] => 01n
                    )

            )

        [dt_txt] => 2018-04-14 21:00:00
    )
```

And there are 36 more. For 8 arrays with the weather for each day with a step of 3 hours.

How do I choose the arrays with the weather exactly at today's date? As you can see, the date is returned - `dt_txt`, but how do I search it correctly?

Comment: Can you include the array as PHP code? also post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: You can iterate over the array and check the `dt` index. The `dt` is the unix time.

Comment: there's a regular base for the time in the array ?
I mean like every 2 hours or 3 hours

Comment: The API doesnt have an option to select a particular day?

Comment: @chris85, this API has option to select a particular day, but it`s paid :c I`m just making TelegramWeatherBot. This API - openweathermap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the array and check using the unix time given:

```
$today_weather = array();
$today = date('Ymd');
foreach($data as $weather){
    // Check if the date is today
    if($today === date('Ymd', $weather['dt'])){
        $today_weather[] = $weather;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** This will add today's weather to `$today_weather`

Comment: I have already tried this, but I need to get those arrays with today`s date, but not only check date :c

Comment: @Біпач I'm not sure what do you mean.. if you can check if the element has today's date then you can do anything you want with it.

Comment: @Біпач If you mean create an array of today's weather check the updated answer even though that's pretty obvious.

Comment: Mehdi, OP wants you to code the whole thing lololol. I've run into a few this week that seem unable to build off of an answer. Most of my accepted answers were me writing the whole thing for an OP. Anyways OP, yeah - you just need to add the date to the array.

Comment: @Nerdi.org well now I see.. He also have a lot of unclosed questions. Check this: [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Why are you comparing strings when you have Unix values?

Comment: @Andreas because IMO it's better than comparing the date against a range (like in your answer) and it looks -for me- cleaner.

Comment: But I don't use the date function `38 x 8 x 2` times. If you read the question it says 38 values in 8 arrays and your code uses date twice on each iteration. Clean or not it will perform better. Also I don't know if it's that hard to read `if is larger than daystart and less than dayend` sound pretty easy to me.

Comment: @Andreas True, but I just tried it and there isn't much difference between [your way](https://3v4l.org/pYcka/perf#output) and [mine](https://3v4l.org/9N7rG/perf#output).

Comment: @Mehdi if you actually think it's not that much difference, why did you change the code? Or did you try to change it to get a better performance and hope I wouldn't notice? Either way, you have not created an array large enough as OP states he got. It's about 8 times larger. So with your original code and `*8` on the figures we get something closer to what OP will get. And with that, my code is about 5-6 times faster depending on version. https://3v4l.org/dfUFO

Comment: @Andreas Chill xD I changed the first `date` because (as you said) I'm getting the date in every iteration, so I improved it....

Comment: Even with your new code it's still quite the difference in my opinion. https://3v4l.org/KUZ06

Comment: @Andreas true, I see the difference now.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the 'dt' item in the array and compare it against the range of Unix seconds during this day.

```
$daystart = strtotime(date("Y-m-d 00:00:00"));
$dayend = strtotime(date("Y-m-d 23:59:59"));
Foreach($arr as $val){
    If($val['dt'] >= $daystart && $val['dt'] <= $dayend){
        $res[] = $val;
    }
}
Var_dump($res);
```

I created a smaller similar array like yours to simulate the use.
https://3v4l.org/kedRX